# "Fell off my person"

Tags: grammaticality

I wanted to ask if it would be accurate to say that "The phone must have fallen off my person!"

Meaning it fell from a purse or a pocket that I carry with me.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that? Only you would know. Would it be grammatical? Certainly. Would it be good English? Not really; at least it's not the way a native speaker would say that. "I must have dropped my phone somewhere!" is what you're more likely to hear.

Comment: What if I want to specifically indicate that it fell off me as I was getting out of a cab or something? Dropped might imply that I was holding the phone.

Comment: Still, *drop* is the most likely verb to be used to express the situation. If it bothers you, substitute *lost*: "I must've lost my phone somewhere!" It is overly specific to explain that you dropped your phone from your "person" ... where else could it have dropped from? If it was in a pocket, say that: "My phone must have fallen out of my pocket!" And so on. Nobody refers to "my person" except in a clinical or legal sense.

Comment: @Robusto However, perhaps in fairness we should give some indication of circumstances in which it might be used. Something wouldn't fall "OFF her person", but FROM her person". If someone asked me "do you have a mobile phone", I could, if it were the case, say "well I don't have one about my person at this moment". It would be a somewhat pretentious way of saying "I don't have one on me...". (One could use it ironically to achieve emphasis.)  But a police officer making a report might say  "cocaine was found on the suspect's person". In other words it is generally reserved for formal use.

Comment: Thanks so much! I realize that the use of 'person' is a bit overly formal for everyday use, and was also wondering whether 'fell off my person' or 'fell from my person' is grammatical.

Comment: In Britain, idiomatically, it would "fall FROM her person", or be found "ON her person", or "ABOUT her person". But Americans tend to use different prepositions to us, so I would not entirely rule out it "falling OFF her person".